# How can I make my custom shortcode work in a Custom HTML Widget?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, widgets, html

I created a plugin and tried to use its shortcode in a [Custom HTML Widget](https://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/custom-html-widget/), but for some reason it's outputting `[my_shortcode_name]` instead of executing the shortcode.

The shortcode works fine if I place it on the page or in a [Text Widget](https://en.support.wordpress.com/widgets/text-widget/).

How can I make it work in a Custom HTML Widget?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding these two lines to my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

The Custom HTML Widget now correctly executes the shortcode function and outputs the result.

Comment: Mark your own answer as **Accepted Answer** to help other people searching solution for same issue.

Comment: @QaisarFeroz - You have to wait two days before accepting your own answer. It's a global Stack Exchange restriction. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6044/258412

Comment: OK, Stay blessed.

Comment: Thanks, for me it worked only with the last filter: add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');